# Why is there condensation on a pipe near my furnace?

Tags: hvac, furnace, condensation

My AC says it is trying to cool to 73 but is reading 75.  I changed the filter, which didn't help.  I looked in the closet, and apparently the installers were supposed to install an "auxiliary shut off switch to a/c condensation line to prevent water damage in case of main drain failure."  I have water condensation dripping down a long white PVC pipe and water collecting on top of the unit.  What is going on with my AC?

Picture 1 shows condensation and the top is just spewing cool air.
[image: Condensation]

Picture 2 is the whole unit.
[image]

Picture 3 is condensation.
[image]

Picture 4 is condensation running down the PVC pipe to the floor of the closet.
[image]

Picture 5 is water pooling on top of the unit where there is green.
[image]

Comment: Cold pipes in a humid climate are going to have condensation on the outside.

Comment: That piece of pipe with wires coming out of it, that says "safety switch" is your aux shutoff switch.  It has a float in there, such that if the bottom vertical piece gets clogged, that will shut off the output before it can overflow the top vertical piece above the T.

Comment: If you look down the open end of the top pipe, do you see standing water pooled in there?

Comment: It looks to me like the condensate drain line is constructed properly and is equipped with a cut-off switch. Also, I don't understand what you mean by "says it is trying to cool to 73 but is reading 75"; you have a *setpoint*, which is the temp you have set the unit to cool to; you have a *room temperature* reading, which is just a thermometer. Are you saying it will not cool the area to the desired setpoint? If it won't, then it needs servicing.

Comment: I do see a **potential problem with the vent**. That vent pipe is likely supposed to be a "B-Type" vent (double-walled) and the straight pipe is but I don't think that adjustable elbow coming from the top of the unit is.

Comment: @MichaelKaras- Okay, thank you for replying.  I live in Arkansas, so it's pretty humid.

Comment: @NateS.- Thank you!  It's at the top of the closet and it was hard to see, so I missed it!  As long as it's there!  Also, I looked down far into the long PVC pipe and didn't see any pooling water.  It's long, but it's nowhere near coming out the top if it's there!

Comment: @JimmyFix-it- Okay, thank you!  I will get it looked into.  It's my first home, and I want to make sure everything is correct!  Yes, I meant it will not cool to the set point.  I'm not very good with explaining it all.  The inspector said it needed to be cleaned, so after changing out the filters, that's my next step before I call in an AC guy.<p>Seriously, guys, THANK YOU!  I am an independent, single woman, but I need help sometimes.

Comment: You are very welcome, BTW sometimes a "non" B-vent is acceptable when it is a part of the vent pipe that does not pass through a wall, ceiling, or roof. It depends on the manufacturer's instructions and your local code.

Comment: I'm curious about the black elbow that's hanging off a zip-tie. What the heck is that for??

Comment: As a community user/editor I removed your backstory and rant. It's not relevant to the question. If you feel like any detail _about the problem_ got lost, feel free to revise further. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how our network operates.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may have a charge related problem. When ac systems start having icing issues they stop effective cooling a low charge can cause ice to form on the evaporator high moisture in the air you see , sometimes with severe icing it takes hours for the ice to melt, the system may run ok for a short period of time then start icing up. A simple recharge can solve this very common problem , if a R22 system note the cost of this refrigerant is very high +100 per pound a 5 ton system usually has 11-13 lbs and will need 5-7 lbs in most cases.